# Python run from subdirectory

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have the following file hierarchy structure:

```
main.py
Main/
      A/
         a.py
         b.py
         c.py
      B/
         a.py
         b.py
         c.py
      C/
         a.py
         b.py
         c.py
```

From main.py I would like to execute any of the scripts in any of the subfolders.

The user will pass on a string A_a.py or B_a.py. The string will be parsed and changed into A/a.py or B/a.py

I would like the approach to be dynamic, such that adding any subfolder for e.g. D with a.py, b.py and c.py would directly adapt without forcing any import lines to the main.py script.

I know it could be done using shell calls like pOpen. But would like to execute it within the code.

Is it possible?

Comment: The short answer: yes, it is possible :) But do you want to run them as separate scripts (so `python C/a.py`) or do they need to be imported and called within the main.py? The second would complicate things.

Comment: The first is easy, system calls popen probably...

I am looking for the second. Will clarify in the question

Comment: What do you mean with 'without forcing any import lines to the main.py script'?

Comment: What is the meaning of `django` tag here?

Comment: @Roelant I don't want to add: from D import *

Comment: @MariusSiuram I am using this code within django server. In case this forces me to add relative directory.

Instead of looking for tag errors, try to focus on the question!

Comment: If it is Django, then specify if you want those scripts to be executed by the administrator or by user requests. If you don't want us messing with Django stuff (like recommending [runscript from django-extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html) ) then simply don't put the tag.

Comment: `try to focus on the question` is seldom a good suggestion, as this typically ends up with an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Note that even adding import lines into the main script will fail because there are no `__init__.py` files. Specify if there is any restriction over the `__init__.py` existance in the subfolders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added empty `__init__.py` files to `Main/, A/, B/, and C/`. I also put the following function in each of the `.py` files just so we had something to call:

```
def f():
    print __name__
```

In `main.py`, the significant function is get_module, which calls [import_module from importlib](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html).

```
import errno
from importlib import import_module
import os
from shutil import copytree
import sys

base = 'Main'

def get_module(arg):
    # 'X_x.py' becomes 'X.x'
    name = arg.strip('.py').replace('_', '.')
    # full_name will be 'Main.X.x'
    full_name = base + '.' + name
    try:
        return import_module(full_name)
    except ImportError as e:
        print e

def main():
    # D is not listed
    print os.listdir(base)
    # works for A
    mod = get_module('A_a.py')
    if mod:
        mod.f()
        # can also call like this
        mod.__dict__['f']()
    # doesn't work for D
    mod = get_module('D_a.py')
    if mod:
        mod.f()
        mod.__dict__['f']()
    # copy files from A to D
    try:
        copytree(os.path.join(base, 'A'),
                 os.path.join(base, 'D'))
    except OSError as e:
        print e
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            sys.exit(-1)
    # D should be listed
    print os.listdir(base)
    # should work for D
    mod = get_module('D_a.py')
    if mod:
        mod.f()
        mod.__dict__['f']()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If all goes well this should be the output:

```
$ python2.7 main.py
['__init__.py', '__init__.pyc', 'A']
Main.A.a
Main.A.a
No module named D.a
['__init__.py', '__init__.pyc', 'D', 'A']
Main.D.a
Main.D.a
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use any import statement then use `os` module
This can be done using `os.system(command)`

```
# main.py
# string = A_a.py, B_b.py
string = raw_input("Enter file to run ")
dirname = string[:1]
filename = string[2:]

os.chdir('Main/'+dirname)
os.system('python %s' %filename)
```

That is another case if the file/directory doesn't exist.